# UITextView - Keyboard Dismiss on Drag or Dismiss Interactively

Tags: ios, swift, keyboard, uitextview, uikeyboard

I'm refactoring the view controller to include the feature to dismiss the keyboard.  The layout has a UITextView and a toolbar (there is no off screen area that the user to dismiss the keyboard) see below -

[image]

In the storyboard, there is an option to dismiss keyboard in different ways in the UITextView and I changed it to dismiss on drag, or dismiss interactively. I don't see any change and couldn't do anything to dismiss the keyboard. How can I get the keyboard to dismiss interactively with the UITextView?

[image]

Comment: I know its not directly related, but use IQKeyboardManager for this, which adds a done button on top of the keyboard which the user can tap to dismiss the keyboard. It has many other features too.  https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQKeyboardManager/tree/master/IQKeyboardManagerSwift

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the built-in keyboard dismissing to work for a `UIScollView` or one of its subclasses (e.g. `UITextView`) the scroll view needs to be able to scroll. If there's not enough text in the text view to provide for scrolling, it won't perform a keyboard dismiss.

However, you can turn on vertical bouncing and then it will work. Check "Bounce Vertically" in interface builder or in code set `myTextView.alwaysBounceVertical = true`.

Comment: jeez, I wouldn't never guessed this one. It worked very well. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can customize your keyboard and add a button for hide keyboard. After that, when you tap to screen, keyboard will appear and you can write again. Here is my sample code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var myTextView: UITextView!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    createToolbar(textField: myTextView)

}

func createToolbar(textField : UITextView) {
    let toolbar = UIToolbar()
    toolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyle.default
    toolbar.sizeToFit()
    let hidekeyboard = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(hidekeyboardd))

    toolbar.items = [hidekeyboard]
    myTextView.inputAccessoryView = toolbar
}

@objc func hidekeyboardd() {
     myTextView.resignFirstResponder()
}
```

Comment: Thanks, and that is my original viewcontroller with the button to dismiss the keyboard. I'm trying to rid of the button and get the keyboard to be swiped down. (real estate screen is expensive :-))